# Tkinter : some questions on Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm working on Notebook and have done the following code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

class Notebook:

    def __init__(self,title):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title(title)
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.root)
        self.add_tab()
        self.run()

    def add_tab(self):
        #Add initial tabs
        frame_notebook_1 = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        frame_notebook_2 = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        frame_notebook_new=ttk.Frame(self.notebook)

        self.notebook .add(frame_notebook_1, text = '--1--')
        self.notebook .add(frame_notebook_2, text = '--2--')
        self.notebook .add(frame_notebook_new, text = '  +  ')

        self.notebook.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

        #Configurate "  +  " tab
        self.new_tab_save_value = tk.StringVar(frame_notebook_new)
        self.new_tab_entry = tk.Entry(frame_notebook_new, textvariable=self.new_tab_save_value,font=('Verdana',10))
        self.new_tab_entry.grid(row=2, column=3,sticky="EW")
        self.new_tab_entry.config(width=17)

        self.button_new = tk.Button(frame_notebook_new, text="Create", command=self.new_tab_return)
        self.button_new.grid(row=3, column=3,sticky="NSEW")
        self.button_new.config(width=17)



    def new_tab_return(self):
        #method to generate a new tab
        frame = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(frame,text="--"+str(len([self.notebook.tab(i, option="text") for i in self.notebook.tabs()]))+"--")
        label = ttk.Label(frame,text=self.new_tab_save_value.get())
        label.grid(column=1,row=1)
        self.notebook.select(len([self.notebook.tab(i, option="text") for i in self.notebook.tabs()])-1)

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

nb = Notebook('Test')
```

I have some questions about that.

FIRST QUESTION : is it possible to modify the tabs order in the notebook? Indeed i'd like to keep the "  +  " tab always in last position.

SECOND QUESTION: When the program generate a new tab, it frame name is just "frame". Is it possible to automatically change the variable name, for example to 'frame_"tabnumber"'  ? Indeed i'd like to work on these frames later so it's not easy if they all have the same name :)

Thanks by advance and sorry for the big messy programm ^^

Comment: For your first question, that seems like a case where you should just use `insert` rather than `add`.

Comment: i do "frame = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)" so it mean that for every new tab, the name will be "frame". I'd like it to be "frame_4 = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)" for tab "--4--", etc

Comment: Thanks @Axe319 it seems to work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you should probably be using `insert`. Additionally, if you want to save multiple variables of the same name, that sounds like a good time to use an array. Here is an example of how that can be achieved.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

class Notebook:
    def __init__(self,title):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title(title)
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.root)
        self.frames = []
        self.add_tab()
        self.run()

    def add_tab(self):
        #Add initial tabs
        self.add_new_tab(initial_entry=True)
        self.add_frame = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)

        self.notebook.add(self.add_frame, text = '  +  ')

        self.notebook.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

        #Configurate "  +  " tab
        self.new_tab_save_value = tk.StringVar(self.add_frame)
        self.new_tab_entry = tk.Entry(self.add_frame, textvariable=self.new_tab_save_value, font=('Verdana',10))
        self.new_tab_entry.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky="EW")
        self.new_tab_entry.config(width=17)

        self.button_new = tk.Button(self.add_frame, text="Create", command=self.add_new_tab)
        self.button_new.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky="NSEW")
        self.button_new.config(width=17)


    def add_new_tab(self, initial_entry=False):
        # since we have an array we know our tab number is always the length
        # of that array
        # so there's no need for list comprehensions to determine the length
        self.frames.append(ttk.Frame(self.notebook))

        if not initial_entry:
            # use insert for our subsequent entries
            self.notebook.insert(len(self.frames) - 1, self.frames[-1], text=f"--{len(self.frames)}--")

            # if you want to modify these labels later, you could also add these
            # to an array.
            label = ttk.Label(self.frames[-1], text=self.new_tab_save_value.get())
            label.grid(column=1, row=1)
        else:
            # use add for our initial entry
            self.notebook.add(self.frames[-1], text=f"--{len(self.frames)}--")

        self.notebook.select(len(self.frames) - 1)


    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

nb = Notebook('Test')
```